# Choosing a proper local address for caddy running inside a container to obtain a proper SSL certificate

Tags: docker, ssl, caddy, caddyfile

My caddy docker container name is `caddy-1` with IP `172.0.0.10`, and my docker host IP is `192.168.1.10`.

Which of below `Caddyfile` block should I use to autogenerate a useful SSL certificate?

A configuration resembling docker host address and port:

```
192.168.1.10:8080 {
    tls internal # for generating locally-trusted certificates
}
```

or a configuration resembling container address in port:

```
172.0.0.10:80 {
    tls internal
}
```

or a configuration resembling container name:

```
caddy-1 {
   tls internal
}
```

?

Potential problems might be:

- Using 172.0.0.10 in my Caddyfile while accessing the server from 192.168.1.10 could lead to a mismatch between the address and SSL certificate.
- Using 192.168.1.10 in my Caddyfile could mean manually moving certificates from inside the container to the host of the container every time they are renewed.

These are just hypothesis, as with every option I tried, Safari blocks the connection not even giving an option to trust certificate manually.